# Writing JavaScript from Objective C in PhoneGap using NSString variables

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

In a PhoneGap application I am trying to return a line of JavaScript from my .m Objective C file. I can do so with no problem with one variable, but the other one fails silently. There appears to be something antagonistic in how the NSString variable *text is declared, but I am new to Objective C and cannot tell what is wrong with the code. See code below.

```
- (void)umSwipe_receivedSwipe:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"umSwipe_receivedSwipe called");
    NSData *data = [notification object];
    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // FAIL: This fails silently
    NSString* orig = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('%@')", text];
    [super writeJavascript:orig];

    // This works great
    NSString* someVar = @"B1234221012341234^LAST/FIRST^151710100000000099000000?;1234221012341234=15171010000000099?";
    NSString* concat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('%@')", someVar];
    [super writeJavascript:concat];
}
```

As background, this is to utilize the [UniMag Magnetic Strip scanner](http://idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/112.html) on iPads.

Why would the one variable work while the other does not, when they contain the same character data? How can I incorporate this variable into a string that I send to JavaScript in an iOS PhoneGap application?

BTW, I am much more likely to appreciate and understand an answer if it has corrected code in it rather than just a link to something.

Thanks.

EDIT: So I've discovered that the error is a JavaScript error. Still not sure what the problem is exactly, but the NSString variable must have some sort of invisible character in it that kills the JS experience. Maybe a line-break that doesn't display when I NSLog it...?

Comment: What do you get when you `NSLog` `data` after ` NSData *data = [notification object];` ?

Comment: It crashes: 2013-09-17 13:00:59.254 HelloWorld[490:707] -[NSConcreteMutableData getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x271780

2013-09-17 13:00:59.256 HelloWorld[490:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x271780'

Comment: If I NSLog(text) I get the following: B1234221012341234^LAST/FIRST^151710100000000099000000?;1234221012341234=15171010000000099?

Comment: ...although with real CC data. Which, of course, I'm not going to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was line breaks. I changed this code:

```
NSString* orig = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('%@')", text];
```

To this:

```
NSString *nolinebreaks = [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSString* orig = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('%@')", nolinebreaks];
```

...and everything is good.

FWIW, to see all JS console.log scripts and also to see JS errors logged into the xcode console, I added the following script toward the top of my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Make the console debugger work properly
    console = new Object();
    console.log = function(log) {
      var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "ios-log:#iOS#" + log);
      document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
      iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
      iframe = null;    
    }
    console.debug = console.log;
    console.info = console.log;
    console.warn = console.log;
    console.error = console.log;
    debug.log = console.log;

    window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber)
    {
        console.log("[Javascript Error]: "+message+" in "+url+" at line "+lineNumber);
    }

</script>
```